# How do I use drilldown with a piechart to get a different value?

Tags: token, pie-chart, splunk, drilldown

I have a field named income where I have the amount of money for each employee per month. I want to show in a pie chart the income types of people.
(|eval income_type= if(income=<4000, "middle class","high class") | stats count by income_type

When I click on the "high class" I want to show in the drilldown which person earns how much money. So I don't want the income_type, I need the income value itself.

How can I get the income value as a token to the drilldown? Now I just get "high class" as a string.

I already tried $row.income$ but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your drilldown will need to use either the `$click.value$` or `$click.value2$` token.

```
<drilldown>
  <link>
  /app/search/simple_xml_form?form.foo=$click.value$
  </link>
</drilldown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SPL ends with a `| stats` section. When you do stats, it removes all previous values from the results. The only values you have left are count and income_type. There is no income field produced anymore in the final results, and if you included the income, your pie chart would have a lot more slices.

Alternatively, drill down to another dashboard that searches by the income_type to provide a list of the incomes that fall within that range. Then you can drilldown from there by clicking on the individual income that you want to view.